# How do you attach a custom callback function to the jquery autocomplete extension?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, callback

I'm using the jquery autocomplete 1.0.2 extension by Dylan Verheul, Dan G. Switzer, Anjesh Tuladhar, Jörn Zaefferer.  I am attempting to execute my own callback function when .show() and .hide() are called from within the autocomplete control.  I haven't found any way for it to actually recognize my callback function.  If anyone is familiar with this control and can help I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have any easy answer to your question, I checked the plugin source code and didn't find any mechanism to let you do want you want. I think you'll have to update this plugin yourself to make it work as you wish.

The idea is to add your callbacks to the `options` parameter and then make the plugin use these callbacks. First, you'll have to modify the plugin code. Go to the function that creates the class in charge of showing/hiding the autocomplete control :

```
$.Autocompleter.Select = function (options, input, select, config) {
```

If you scroll down, you can see that this function returns an object with `show()` and `hide()` methods. You can add the following code :

```
hide: function() {
    ...
    options.showCallback && options.showCallback(); // Invoke callback function if set
},
...
show: function() {
    ...
    options.hideCallback && options.hideCallback(); // Invoke callback function if set
},
```

Finally, when you create your autocomplete, you should add your callbacks to your options:

```
$("#myTextBox").autocomplete("http://...",
{
    showCallback : function() { /* do what you want here */ },
    hideCallback : function() { /* do what you want here */ }
});
```

Not tested at all, it's just a quick and dirty solution. I hope this helps.

Comment: it works!  you're awesome!  I actually have the show and hide callback functions that I want called pre-defined, so I just do showCallback:myShow, hideCallback:myHide and it just works, thanks again!

Comment: Great ;) You can try to submit the idea/code to the authors, they might be interested.

Comment: Well done. Something like this is available in the new version of jquery-autocomplete:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete