# A good autocomplete plugin for jQuery 1.3?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm at my wits end with this one because there doesn't seem to be anything viable for this.

I have tried using jQuery UI's autocomplete from SVN, which can be found here: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dev/autocomplete/

But the total lack of (updated) documentation has got me as far as displaying a bunch of [Object]'s in my result list, with no clue how to format it.

I just want a simple autocomplete plugin that:

- Allows me to return a JSON object that the plugin itself will parse
- Allows me to specify a seperate inputField from the displayField so that the user sees "Stackoverflow Industries" but the input field is actuall "5", the companies id.
- Obviously, does the basics that an autocomplete plugin will do

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a small example using this plugin to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612045/jquery-autocomplete-for-input-form-using-textpattern-category-list-as-a-source/612208#612208). In this example, it's not a "JSON object", but an "option" object (yeah... don't ask...) that is handled by the plugin and the value of the option is stored in a hidden field while the text is shown in the textbox. The best thing to do is to have a look at the [demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) and inspect the code to understand the options you can use. And why not extend the plugin to let it have the exact behaviour you want it to ? It's not [that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610847/how-to-you-attach-a-custom-callback-function-to-the-jquery-autocomplete-extension/611218#611218).

Anyway, just give a live example of what you need, and we'll try to help you :)

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that jQuery plugin you linked not available for jQuery 1.3?

Comment: I've been using the bassistance.de AutoComplete plugin with jQ 1.3 for a while without problem.

Comment: Thanks James, I was not sure myself, so I just ran some tests and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: James: Wow, just wow. I think I want to shoot myself in the face. Either way, thanks .. I will give that one a go tomorrow.